# Integrate $\int \frac{1}{1+\arctan(x)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

Consider:

$$\int \frac{1}{1+\arctan(x)}dx$$

I have attempted with making $x=\tan(u)$ and $\frac{dx}{du}=\sec^2(u)$

then ended up with:

$$\int \frac{\sec^2(u)}{1+u}du$$

$$\int \frac{1+\tan^2(u)}{1+u}du$$

$$\int \frac{1}{1+u}du+\int \frac{\tan^2(u)}{1+u}du$$

$$\ln\left|1+\arctan(x)\right|+\int \frac{\tan^2(u)}{1+u}du$$

And I do not know what to do from there on.

Comment: any reason to believe that a simple closed form exists?

Comment: http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=tan%28x%29^2%2F%281%2Bx%29&random=false

Comment: When graphed on calculator, appears to give a similar type to $1/x$

Comment: u shouldn't look to much on the graphs of integrands but rather think about their structure

Comment: Still having a hard time integrating this.

Answer (score 6):

There exists no solution in terms of standard mathematical functions. This can be proven using [Risch Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm). This is not something I recommend you do by hand.

The most easy way to check if an integral has a solution is by [asking Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%201%2F(1%2Batan(x))) which uses this algorithm or a better one to guarantee a solution is it exists. Otherwise, it displays:

> (no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions)

[To back up my claim:](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html)

> For indefinite integrals, an extended version of the Risch algorithm
>   is used whenever both the integrand and integral can be expressed in
>   terms of elementary functions, exponential integral functions,
>   polylogarithms, and other related functions.

Comment: There is definitely a way to do this, we just have not found it yet.

Comment: @Kenny what makes you think that?

Comment: Well there are yet a lot of things to discover and many concepts we do not know yet stays hidden.

Comment: What I'm trying to tell you is that we know for sure that the integral does not exist in terms of standard mathematical functions. Think of it like this, say we had no log, than 1/x would not have an integral. This can be **proven** using risch algorithm and wolfram alpha uses it. Of course you can give the answer using an infinite sum or definite integral, but thats easy to find for any integral and not what you are looking for I guess

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure this doesn't have a closed form. A change of variable and integration by parts got me to:
$$\int \frac{dx}{1 + \arctan(x)} = \frac{x}{1 + \arctan(x)} + \int \frac{\tan(y)}{(1 + y)^2}dy$$
WolframAlpha says the right-most integral has no closed form, and I can't think of anything useful to do with it. It might have some cute definite integral values?

Comment: Is there any way to integrate $\int \frac{\tan (y)}{(1+y)^2}dy$?

Comment: @KennyGuy most propably not!